# Chronometer Share between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os, android-fragmentactivity

I have a FragmentActivity that has 3 fragments attached.This 3 fragments have a chronometer and i want them to share the same time between them...

- I've tried to start() them all at same time but sometimes they suddenly start over from 00.00...
- I've tried to store the time on the FragmentActivity through onChronometerTick() but it seems to not work...

Can someone give me an idea how to do what i want?

Fragment 1

```
public class Run1Fragment extends Fragment {
private Chronometer chronometer;
private WearRunActivity runActivity;
private Run2Fragment run2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_run1, container, false);
    chronometer = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    runActivity = new WearRunActivity();
    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(runActivity);
    chronometer.start();

    return view;
}
```

Fragment 2

```
public class Run2Fragment extends Fragment {
private Chronometer r2Chronometer;
Run1Fragment run1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_run2, container, false);
    r2Chronometer = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    /*r2Chronometer.setBase(run1.getChronometer().getBase());
    r2Chronometer.start();*/

    return view;
}
```

FragmentActivity onChronometerTick listener

```
@Override
public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
    System.out.println("CRONOMETROOOO");
    this.chronometer.setBase(chronometer.getBase());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution!

Instead of creating an chronometer for all fragments, i've integrated it in the fragmentactivity fragment, so only the text i want to change will be placed in other fragment.